# undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

ruby version => ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]

While installing rails on my local env I m getting this error.

```
gem install rails

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)

undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass
```

Any help is going to be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem.

I have ruby version:

```
$ruby -v
#=> ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]
```

and in gem environment I have ruby gem version:

```
  $ gem env
  #=>RubyGems Environment:
  #=>- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
```

now I checked the rvm list gemsets and select the ruby-2.2.0.

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.2.0
```

Again I run the command.

```
$gem install rails
```

This time it is working fine.

In nutshell the issue was I had the old ruby version while I had the newer RubyGem! Cheers!