# rvm deafult ruby version working other version not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

When I installed rvm it default  install ruby `2.2.1` and it is working fine.

I have installed another version `rvm install 2.1.0` and installed.

When I use 2.1.0 and run `bundle install` I get:

```
/home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:7:in `<main>'
```

I tried to `gem install bundler` give me: `ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError) undefined method`ord' for nil:NilClass`

If I use ruby 2.2.1 then bundle install working.

when I am using `rvm use 2.1.0` then `which bundle` give me: /usr/bin/bundle
when I am using `rvm use 2.2.1` then `which bundle` give me: /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/bundle

Here is the output of `gem env` :

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.1 (2015-02-26 patchlevel 85) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/awlad/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin
     - /home/awlad/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
```

Additional info:

```
 rvm 1.26.11
 Bundler version 1.10.6
```

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Once try in `ruby 2.1.0` run this: `gem install bundler` and the `bundle install`

Comment: gem install bundler give me: 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Please post the complete error log which you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering and accepting this question because someone may get help from this.

After investigating I have found that it is a Ruby bug was fixed [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9498#change-45180)

I had to upgrade ruby version to 2.1.7 to solve this issue.

You can get details from [rvm issue tracker.](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3498)

Answer (score 2):

When you switch from one ruby version to another using rvm and you get that message, then you should install bundler again:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Comment: `gem install bundler` gives :
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437960/undefined-method-ord-for-nilnilclass
This could be helpful, may be?

Answer (score 1):

cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError) This is the error. The bundler is missing for 2.1.0 . Run gem install bundler and then bundle install

Comment: gem install bundler gives : ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError) undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass

Comment: There is an error in your code somewhere for a class which doesn't exists and ord is called with it or its object. Check line number and paste full error.